# How to fix "ValueError: Could not interpret input 'User'" error in Seaborn bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, seaborn

## Problem

I'm trying to plot a categorical bar chart in Seaborn with the categories set by a value in the `DataFrame` (`Favourites`). Why is Seaborn throwing an error when I try to pass this value into the `hue` keyword in the `barplot` function?

## What I've Tried

I have tried to separate the DataFrame into two differnt DataFrames so that they can be plotted together but could only get a stacked bar chart rather than a side-by-side categorical one.

I saw on the Seaborn docs that passing the category column name to the `hue` keyword allows data to be categorised but I always receive an error message when I try to pass `Favourites` to it.

## Code for DataFrame:

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

data_frame['User'] = numpy.array([tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets])
#data_frame['ID'] = numpy.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
#data_frame['Length'] = numpy.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Date'] = numpy.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
#data_frame['Source'] = numpy.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Favourites'] = numpy.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
#data_frame['Retweets'] = numpy.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
data_frame['Day'] = data_frame['Date'].dt.day_name()
data_frame.set_index(['User'],inplace=True)
```

## Code for Plotting:

```
frames = [user1, user2]
result = pandas.concat(frames)
x = result.Day
y = result.Favourites


result.groupby('Day',as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True).agg({'Favourites':'sum'})
#user2.groupby('Day',as_index=False, sort=True, group_keys=True).agg({'Favourites':'sum'})


plotted = sns.barplot(x,y,color="skyblue",data=result,hue='User',order=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])


sns_plot = plotted.get_figure()
sns_plot.savefig('plot.png')
```

## Example Data

```
User            Date        Favourites  Day

AOC             1/3/2019    500         Monday

AOC             2/3/2019    200         Tuesday

realDonaldTrump 3/3/2019    600         Wednesday

realDonaldTrump 4/3/2019    700         Thursday
```

## Expected vs. Actual Results

I want a barchart like so: [image: this]

This is the error/stack trace I receive:[image: this]

## SOLVED

The issue was down this line in the DataFrame definition (which I removed),
`data_frame.set_index(['User'],inplace=True)`

Comment: The error tells you that the dataframe you supply via `data` does not have a column named `"user"`.

Comment: If you check the code for the DataFrame, you can see it is the very first column.

Comment: I'd rather trust the error than the posted printout here. You may provide a [mcve] such that people can find out more.

Comment: What does the result dataframe look like right before the call to sns.barplot?

Comment: I printed result.head() just before the sns.barplot call and the User column is printed

Comment: print `result.columns`

Comment: It wasn't there; turns out setting it as the index was what caused the problem.